# Datatables - Keeping only selected page number(not order or search or filter) after callback and clear on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, savestate

I have a data table which I should change something on it, for example, I want to change the title of the content, but this content is on the 6th page of the table. When I change it, the data table refreshes itself to the 1st page. What I'm trying to do is to keep the selected page number and call it back after refresh. I have tried all solutions but I just want to save page number nothing else. Is that possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        var dataTableoOBJ = $("#forumList").dataTable({
        "lengthChange": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/admin/forums/data",
        "createdRow": function (row, data, rowIndex) {
         $.each($('td', row), function (colIndex) {
         $(this).attr('data-id', data.id);
         });
        },
        'columns': [{...}]
        });
        });
</script>
```

I have also tried

`"saveState": true` and for clearing state on refresh/reload

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1){
   var table = $('#forumList').DataTable();
   table.state.clear();
   table.ajax.reload();
}
```

but it's only clearing page numbers is there any way to clear sorting/ordering/searching/filtering?

Comment: Check This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158375/datatables-keeping-selected-page-number-after-callback

Comment: I have tried but it's saving all states like ordering, searching and etc. I just want to save the page number of the data table. Or else is there any way to clear all states including order, search, filter, etc. on refreshing the whole page?

Comment: Check this Out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402208/remove-search-filter-on-datatable

Comment: Yeah, thanks! It's working. Btw I have found another solution for my problem, I'm adding 2 solutions for this question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got 2 solutions for this problem.

***Solution 1:***

Add these fields to the data table

```
 "stateSave": true,
 stateLoadParams: function( settings, data ) {
      var a = data.order;
      if(data.search.search !== '' || a[0][0] !== 0 || data.length !== 10) {
           delete data.order;
           delete data.search;
           delete data.length;
           delete data.start;
           window.location.reload();
       }
       if (data.start === 0) {
           delete data.order;
           delete data.search;
           delete data.length;
           delete data.start;
       }
  }
```

And required actions for refreshing the page

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1){
     var table = $('#forumList').DataTable();
     table.state.clear();
     table.ajax.reload();
}
```

***Solution 2:***

Add `"stateSave": true` field to the data table

And required actions for refreshing the page

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1){
  var table = $('#forumList').DataTable();
  table.state.clear();
  table.search("").draw(); 
  table.column( '0:visible' ).order( 'asc' ).draw();
  table.page.len(10).draw();
}
```